# Updating projectVersion key in sonar properties file using package.json version value

Tags: jenkins, gulp, sonarqube, package.json

I have a fairly standard web application setup which makes use of nodejs libraries.

I have a SonarQube analysis build step set up on Jenkins which makes use of a sonar project properties file in the root of my project directory.

I was wondering if there are any gulp plugins that will update the `projectVersion` key in the sonar properties file using the version number value found in my projects package.json file.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: When you say a "standard web application", what technology is it built upon? (apart from JS obviously)

Comment: Is just an SPA using AngularJs but also with a server side node express application. All I want is a way to automate updating the version number for SonarQube analysis using whatever version number is in my projects package.json file

Answer (score 3):

Using the [SonarQube Scanner for JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sonarqube-scanner) will allow you to easily analyze your JS code and read the version information from the `package.json` file.

Comment: Ok well I'm using the Jenkins [plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) version of the scanner instead